# Can I run the jenkins high level stages in parallel?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a groovy script to some tests in parallel but I cannot restart the stages Installation1/Installation2 manually from the jenkins UI. Is there any other way to do this so that I can restart a specific stage?

```
pipeline {
     agent {label ''}
     stages {
             stage('Check workspace') {
             steps {
             }
             }
             stage('Installation') {
             parallel{
                        stage('Installation 1')
                        {
                        agent {label ''}
                        steps {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                        stage('Installation 2')
                        {
                        agent {label ''}
                        steps {
                            }
                        }
                    }
             }
             }
             stage('Test') {
             parallel{
                        stage(' Tests 1'){
                        agent {label ''}
                        steps {
                            }
                        }
                        stage(' Tests 2'){
                        agent {label ''}
                        steps {
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    }
             stage('Report') {
             steps {
             }
             }  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Consider to use "parameters" mixed with conditionals ("when") at the stages

Answer (score 0):

You can define the installation1 and installation2 stages as functions in your Jenkinsfile and call them when the test fails. These functions can be used for installation stage as well as re-installation when the tests fails.

```
def installation1() {
   stage('Installation 1')
                        {
                        agent {label ''}
                        steps {
                            }
                        }
}

def installation2() {
   stage('Installation 2')
                        {
                        agent {label ''}
                        steps {
                            }
                        }
}
```

In Parallel step, you can call the functions as below. Use try-catch to call install functions when tests fail.

```
 stage('Test') {
   try {
     "TEST YOUR INSTALLATION"
   } catch(error) {
     echo "First test failed, let's retry installation if accepted"
     retry(2) {
        input "Retry the installation ?"
        parallel{
           installation1(),
           installation2()
      }
     }
   }
}
```

This code is not tested. Hope it helps :)